# What is the best way to do this parsing using streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I wanted to know how we can do the below parsing cleanly with streams. Here I am trying to change a List of Maps into Maps of Maps.
I am parsing as below

**Input:**

```
[ 
   { 
      "productId":1,
      "price":2,
      "noOfBuyers":6
   },
   { 
      "productId":2,
      "price":5,
      "noOfBuyers":8
   },
   { 
      "productId":1,
      "rating":5
   }
]
```

I want to club the details about a particular product into one map. I cannot create a product object as the fields inside it will differ every time.

**Parse the above json to:**

```
{
   "1" : {
    "productId":1
    "price":2,
    "noOfBuyers":6,
    "rating":5
   },
   "2":{ 
    "productId":2,
    "price":5,
    "noOfBuyers":8
   }

}
```

```
private void parseResponse(Map<String, Map<String, Object>> response, List<Map<String, Object>> s) {
     if(s.size() > 0) {
            for (Map<String, Object> maps : s) {
                if (maps != null && maps.containsKey("productId")) {
                    String productId = maps.get("productId").toString();
                    if (!response.containsKey(productId))
                        response.put(productId, maps);
                    else {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: maps.entrySet()) {
                            response.get(productId).put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: First of... instead of `List<Map<String, Object>>`..Make it a `List<SomeObject>`... where SomeObject is an object that you create that contains an `abcd` field and a `cde` field.

Comment: First JSON is invalid. Did you mean for the outer `{ }` to be `[ ]`?

Comment: Hey, this is a dynamic object which can contain the required field or not, we cannot use simple POJO for this.

Comment: Andreas Corrected it

Comment: @amazing_milkha fields can be null...

Comment: And what id do you use when the field is not there........

Comment: Yes, i am also not sure what fields may come only sure element is abcd. If abcd is not there will not consider that map altogether in the list

Comment: You are going to need to post more clarifying information... what do you do when abcd is not there....also give us an idea of what the real world application is of this... otherwise we're just grasping at straws

Comment: @RobOhRob Why? OP is simply asking for the stream version of the given method. The method has the logic that needs to be implemented using streams. Of course, the code is flawed, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @RobOhRob added more explanation  ,is it OK

Comment: Now that the code contradicts the example, could you confirm if making changes to remove `productId` from output is intentional?

Comment: where it contradicts @Naman

Comment: @amazing_milkha What would be the output if the input is `[ 
   { 
      "productId":1,
      "price":2,
      "noOfBuyers":6
   },
   { 
      "productId":2,
      "price":5,
      "noOfBuyers":8
   },
   { 
      "productId":1,
      "rating":5, "price":5
   }
]`

Comment: @Naman Obvious from the code in the question, the last version of a value wins, so: `{ "1":{ "productId":1, "price":5, "noOfBuyers":6, "rating":5 }, 2:{ "productId":2, "price":5, "noOfBuyers":8 } }`

Comment: @RobOhRob Well, you're right, I'm assuming `response.get("productId")` is supposed to be `response.get(productId)`, otherwise it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Andreas You are right while changing I have mistyped, it is response.get(productId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED:*** Changed to use new sample data from updated question (version 5).

Using streams, the method can be implemented like this:

```
private static Map<String, Map<String, Object>> convertResponse(List<Map<String, Object>> response) {
    return response.stream()
            .filter(maps -> maps != null && maps.containsKey("productId"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(maps -> maps.get("productId").toString(),
                                      Function.identity(),
                                      (m1, m2) -> { m1.putAll(m2); return m1; }));
}
```

*Test*

```
List<Map<String, Object>> response = List.of(
        new HashMap<>(Map.of("productId", 1, "price", 2, "noOfBuyers", 6)),
        new HashMap<>(Map.of("productId", 2, "price", 5, "noOfBuyers", 8)),
        new HashMap<>(Map.of("productId", 1, "rating", 5)));
System.out.println(response);

Map<String, Map<String, Object>> converted = convertResponse(response);
System.out.println(converted);
```

*Output*

```
[{productId=1, noOfBuyers=6, price=2}, {productId=2, noOfBuyers=8, price=5}, {rating=5, productId=1}]
{1={rating=5, productId=1, noOfBuyers=6, price=2}, 2={productId=2, noOfBuyers=8, price=5}}
```

---

From comment:

> The use case is such that I need to make changes to response map that I am sending as parameter in the function. Lets say this function is used by *parallel* running apis that get the data, use this function to add data into that response.

If this method is called by *parallel* running apis, then it needs to be thread-safe, and the code in the question is not thread-safe.

To ensure full thread-safety, the `response` map must be a concurrent map. If so, the code can be implemented using streams as follows (although it's not really using streams for much, and might as well have stayed a `for` loop):

```
private static void parseResponse(Map<String, Map<String, Object>> response, List<Map<String, Object>> s) {
    s.stream()
     .filter(maps -> maps != null && maps.containsKey("productId"))
     .forEach(maps ->
        response.merge(maps.get("productId").toString(),
                       new HashMap<>(maps),
                       (m1, m2) -> {
                           Map<String, Object> merged = new HashMap<>(m1);
                           merged.putAll(m2);
                           return merged;
                       }));
}
```

Comment: here you are returning the Map, But the use case is such that I need to make changes to response map that I am sending as parameter in the function. Lets say this function is used by parallel running apis that get the data, use this function to add data into that response and when all the APIs completes, we need to send the clubbed response.

Comment: @amazing_milkha Parallel? Your code is not thread-safe, so no attempt to make this thread-safe of shared map was done. Anyway, if you want to merge with existing map, keep your code, don't try to make it streaming.

Comment: I am using java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap. How come not thread safe

Comment: @amazing_milkha You're using `if (!response.containsKey(productId)) { response.put(productId, maps); }`, but by the time the code reaches `put`, the map might contain that key, added by another thread between the calls to `containsKey` and `put`.